# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader couldn't find "liblivecamera.so.so"

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, tesseract

I am working on camera application. When I debug the application, it crashes and says

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kuQobL0-J_-5EsHI7x5ShQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kuQobL0-J_-5EsHI7x5ShQ==/lib/arm64,
> /data/app/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-kuQobL0-J_-5EsHI7x5ShQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
> /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "liblibcamera.so.so"

It is showing this error at this line of code:-

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("livecamera");
    }
```

My complete **cameraview.java** code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements Camera.PreviewCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        OCRThread.TextRegionsListener {

    private final List<Rect> regions = new ArrayList<>();

    private Camera mCamera;
    private byte[] mVideoSource;
    private Bitmap mBackBuffer;
    private OCRThread ocrThread;

    private Paint focusPaint;
    private Rect focusRect;

    private Paint paintText;

    private float horizontalRectRation;
    private float verticalRectRation;


    static {
        System.loadLibrary("livecamera");
    }

    public CameraView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CameraView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        focusPaint = new Paint();
        focusPaint.setColor(0xeed7d7d7);
        focusPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        focusPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        focusRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

        paintText = new Paint();
        paintText.setColor(0xeeff0000);
        paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paintText.setStrokeWidth(4);

        ocrThread = new OCRThread(context);
        horizontalRectRation = 1.0f;
        verticalRectRation = 1.0f;
    }

    public void setShowTextBounds(final boolean show) {
        regions.clear();
        ocrThread.setRegionsListener(show ? this : null);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void makeOCR(final OCRThread.TextRecognitionListener listener) {
        ocrThread.setTextRecognitionListener(listener);
    }

    public native void decode(final Bitmap pTarget, final byte[] pSource);


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (focusRect.width() > 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(focusRect, focusPaint);
        }
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
            drawTextBounds(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void drawTextBounds(final Canvas canvas) {
        for (Rect region : regions) {
            canvas.drawRect(region.left * horizontalRectRation, region.top * verticalRectRation,
                    region.right * horizontalRectRation, region.bottom * verticalRectRation, paintText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] bytes, final Camera camera) {
        decode(mBackBuffer, bytes);
        ocrThread.updateBitmap(mBackBuffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
            startOcrThread();
        } catch (IOException eIOException) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private void startOcrThread() {
        ocrThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, final int format, final int width, final int height) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        Size lSize = findBestResolution();
        updateTextRectsRatio(width, height, lSize);
        PixelFormat lPixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
        PixelFormat.getPixelFormatInfo(mCamera.getParameters()
                .getPreviewFormat(), lPixelFormat);
        int lSourceSize = lSize.width * lSize.height * lPixelFormat.bitsPerPixel / 8;
        mVideoSource = new byte[lSourceSize];
        mBackBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(lSize.width, lSize.height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Camera.Parameters lParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        lParameters.setPreviewSize(lSize.width, lSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(lParameters);
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mVideoSource);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    private Size findBestResolution() {
        List<Size> lSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size lSelectedSize = mCamera.new Size(0, 0);
        for (Size lSize : lSizes) {
            if ((lSize.width >= lSelectedSize.width) && (lSize.height >= lSelectedSize.height)) {
                lSelectedSize = lSize;
            }
        }
        if ((lSelectedSize.width == 0) || (lSelectedSize.height == 0)) {
            lSelectedSize = lSizes.get(0);
        }
        return lSelectedSize;
    }

    private void updateTextRectsRatio(final int width, final int height, final Size cameraSize) {
        verticalRectRation = ((float) height) / cameraSize.width;
        horizontalRectRation = ((float) width) / cameraSize.height;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            mVideoSource = null;
            mBackBuffer = null;
            stopOcrThread();
        }
    }

    private void stopOcrThread() {
        boolean retry = true;
        ocrThread.cancel();
        ocrThread.setRegionsListener(null);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                ocrThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            Rect touchRect = new Rect(
                    (int) (x - 100),
                    (int) (y - 100),
                    (int) (x + 100),
                    (int) (y + 100));

            final Rect targetFocusRect = new Rect(
                    touchRect.left * 2000 / this.getWidth() - 1000,
                    touchRect.top * 2000 / this.getHeight() - 1000,
                    touchRect.right * 2000 / this.getWidth() - 1000,
                    touchRect.bottom * 2000 / this.getHeight() - 1000);

            doTouchFocus(targetFocusRect);
            focusRect = touchRect;
            invalidate();

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    focusRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    invalidate();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void doTouchFocus(final Rect tfocusRect) {
        try {
            final List<Camera.Area> focusList = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
            Camera.Area focusArea = new Camera.Area(tfocusRect, 1000);
            focusList.add(focusArea);

            Camera.Parameters para = mCamera.getParameters();
            para.setFocusAreas(focusList);
            para.setMeteringAreas(focusList);
            mCamera.setParameters(para);
            mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    Camera.AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            if (arg0) {
                mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onTextRegionsRecognized(final List<Rect> textRegions) {
        regions.clear();
        regions.addAll(textRegions);
        invalidate();
    }
}

``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the statement:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("libcamera.so");
}
```

`System.loadLibrary` is a Java method for loading a library in a platform-independant way, which means you don't have to specify the platform specific filename of the library, but instead you need to use the library name so without `lib` at the beginning and `.so` at the end. Java will make it platform specific for Linux by adding both.

So you have to change it to

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("camera");
}
```

and it will work and load `libcamera.so` (if this library is included in your app).

Comment: It is "so so" obvious :-)

Comment: yes . but this library not present . then how can I download this.

Comment: @RishiFf The command is included in your code so how should I know what library it is? Usually programmer only include commands and libraries for a good reason. So if you don't have that library why have you included this command?